# Error: Compiling simple PjSIP program under ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, sip, pjsip

I am trying to compile simple PjSIP program under ubuntu. I am getting error as

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsua-i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

What does it mean?

Here is the ouput:-

> root@mypc-desktop:/home/mypc/pjsip# make

`gcc -o myapp myapp.cpp -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -I/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjlib/include -I/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjlib-util/include -I/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjnath/include -I/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjmedia/include -I/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjsip/include -L/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjlib/lib -L/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjlib-util/lib -L/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjnath/lib -L/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjmedia/lib -L/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjsip/lib -L/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/third_party/lib  -lpjsua-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpjsip-ua-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpjsip-simple-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpjsip-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-codec-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-audiodev-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpjnath-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpjlib-util-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lresample-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lmilenage-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lsrtp-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lgsmcodec-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lspeex-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lilbccodec-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lg7221codec-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lportaudio-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lpj-i686-pc-linux-gnu -lm -lnsl -lrt -lpthread`

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpjsua-i686-pc-linux-gnu
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [myapp] Error 1`

Here is code

```
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjmedia.h>
#include <pjmedia-codec.h>
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjsip_simple.h>
#include <pjsip_ua.h>
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

Here is a Makefile

```
#Modify this to point to the PJSIP location.
PJBASE=/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5

include $(PJBASE)/build.mak

CC      = $(APP_CC)
LDFLAGS = $(APP_LDFLAGS)
LDLIBS  = $(APP_LDLIBS)
CFLAGS  = $(APP_CFLAGS)
CPPFLAGS= ${CFLAGS}

# If your application is in a file named myapp.cpp or myapp.c
# this is the line you will need to build the binary.
all: myapp

myapp: myapp.cpp
        $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
        rm -f myapp.o myapp
```

Thanks

EDIT:

I just noticed that there is a error building PjSIP

> make[2]: Entering directory
>   `/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjnath/build'
>   gcc -c -Wall  -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2
>
>   -Wno-unused-label -Werror -I../include -I../../pjlib/include -I../../pjlib-util/include \         -o output/pjnath-i686-pc-linux-gnu/stun_session.o
>   \         ../src/pjnath/stun_session.c  cc1:
>   warnings being treated as errors
>   ../src/pjnath/stun_session.c: In
>   function ‘apply_msg_options’:
>   ../src/pjnath/stun_session.c:230:
>   error: suggest parentheses around &&
>   within || make[2]: ***
>   [output/pjnath-i686-pc-linux-gnu/stun_session.o]
>   Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory`
>   /home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjnath/build'
>   make[1]: *** [pjnath] Error 2 make[1]:
>   Leaving directory
>   `/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjnath/build'
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

When I tried to find -Werror in make files present at `/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjnath/build`, `$(PJDIR)/build.mak` and `$(PJDIR)/build/common.mak`  its not present there anybody know where it could be ?

Comment: is there a `pjsua-i686-pc-linux-gnu.so` in one of the `/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pj*` ?

Comment: i mean `/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pj*/lib/`

Comment: @gf: No there is not in any of them

Comment: Should `$(PJBASE)/build.mak` build it or is it supposed to have been built already?

Comment: I build it using './configure' , 'make dep' and 'make'

Comment: Oops, i missed your response, sorry. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: yep...I found -Werror under $(pjProject_root)/user.mak.. everything worked perfectly after removing -Werror .. thanks :)

Comment: Ok, great. Somehow SO doesn't always notify me of new comments to my answer :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the pj* can't build the neccessary libaries - for a simple fix try to locate the line in `/home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/build.mak` where `-Werror` is added to `$(APP_CFLAGS)` and remove it (the `-Werror`, not the whole line if other flags are added :).

Alternatively apply the fix suggested by gcc on line 230 in `src/pjnath/stun_session.c`.

**edit:**
Just read that you found no `-Werror`. Could you either paste line 230 of stun_session.c or the make-files somewhere?
The source line would be preferred.

Comment: Line 230: PJ_STUN_IS_REQUEST(msg->hdr.type) && msg->hdr.magic==PJ_STUN_MAGIC)) ... /home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/build.mak - http://pastebin.com/m160fdd7f  .../home/mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/pjnath/build/Makefile - http://pastebin.com/m6c8e8fd7 .../mypc/pjproject-1.4.5/build/common.mak - http://pastebin.com/m1576134a....  src/pjnath/stun_session.c - http://pastebin.com/m3c994419